# Share container started in a job to subsequent jobs in a linear pipeline

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, cicd, docker-in-docker

I'm using docker executor with DinD, and I was wondering if it's possible to start a container in a pipeline job, and then keep using it till the end of jobs of a pipeline. Jobs are sequentially, cannot be run in parallel and should run on the same host computer. I want to save time in downloading in each job the same image from the Gitlab Container Registry over and over again. Image is not lightweight and heavy.

Is this possible?